# Blue-Green Software Mascot

Tags: identify-this-software

I recall seeing a mascot for some sort of computer platform or program. I've seen images many times, but am now struggling to find it. Here are the details I can remember:

- I think it was a 1990s thing, but may have been late 80s or early 2000s
- The character was vaguely human shaped, but looked like a frog or alien. It had smooth blue or green skin, a potbelly, large eyes, and I believe was sometimes depicted with aviator goggles.
- It was rendered, or drawn, in 3D
- The image was reused in different poses, etc

My first thought was that it was related to some piece of Amiga software, but I can't find anything like that on the internet.

Edit: To be clear, I was not thinking of a game character, and in fact, comments and the accepted answer show that the image had nothing to do with software at all, and my memory just sucks.

Comment: Just to clarify: This character was also the player's sprite, the hero of the game? Or was it the player's nemesis? Or something else altogether (i.e. an NPC)? Please [edit] your post to clarify this point. By the way, are you sure it isn't [crazy frog](https://www.google.com/search?q=crazy+frog)? He had glasses but was for ring tones.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm going to have to guess *[Crazy Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog)*, for the following reasons:

- 2003/2004 (which is sort of early 2000s)
- Grey/blue/green in colour (teal?)
- Pot belly
- Large eyes
- (Motorcycle) goggles
- 3D rendered (although some versions could be just 2D animation)
- Many poses

Negatives:

- 2003/2004 (nowhere near the late 1980s)
- Ringtone mascot and not a game software mascot (may also be considered a [popstar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k85mRPqvMbE)?)

[image: Crazy frog]

Comment: Who else :))) Rängdängdäng ....

Comment: It's 100% this. I'm not sure why I had a software association. I think that this was maybe used as a demo image in a screenshot of some older software somewhere? (ie a screenshot made after the obsolescence of the system).

Comment: @rightbrace Well, ringtones - and that's where the character was used over and over - are some kind of software :)

Comment: We should appreciate the wise choice of name for that character by Erik Wernquist, the original creator of the design: Crazy Frog was already called "The Annyoing Thing" *before* this character appeared in TV adverts by Jamba.

Answer (score 9):

Could it be the logo from [Sirius Software, Inc.](https://www.mobygames.com/company/3433/sirius-software-inc/), the California-based publisher of games for 8-bit home computers of the 1980s?  The logo depicts a chubby, green, humanoid alien.  I'm not sure whether or not the alien was ever depicted in different poses, though.

[image: The Sirius Software, Inc. logo, showing a chubby, green, humanoid alien with a trademark symbol and the text "Sirius" underneath.]

Answer (score 4):

When you mention the Amiga, the first artist that comes to mind was Eric Schwartz, who created a character called Flip the Frog (among others).

[image]